# Salesforce Account Owner Name on Case Trigger failing

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I wrote a trigger that places the Account Owner Name on a Case created for that Account. It works and performs also in my bulk test of 200. Here is the code:

```
trigger CaseBeforeInsertUpdate on Case (before insert, before update) {

   Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
   Set<Id> accountOwnerIds = new Set<Id>(); 

   for (Case c : Trigger.new) {
        if(c.AccountId != null) {
            accountIds.add(c.AccountId);
        }       
   }
   Map<Id,Account> accountMap = new Map<Id, Account>([select Id, OwnerId from Account where Id IN :accountIds]);

   for (Account a : accountMap.values()) {
        if(a.OwnerId != null) {
            accountOwnerIds.add(a.OwnerId);
        }
   }

   Map<Id, User> userMap = new Map<Id,User>([select Name from User where Id IN :accountOwnerIds]);

   if(userMap.size() > 0) {
        for(Case c: Trigger.new) {  
            c.MerchantOwner__c = userMap.get(accountMap.get(c.AccountId).OwnerId).name;
        }
   }

}
```

By accident I discovered a bug and I can't figure out what is going wrong. If I go to a Case listview (i.e. My open cases) and select multiple Cases and Close them, I get an error: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object for the row that updates the MerchantOwner field. When I mass close cases in my testclass everything works fine..

My best guess is I'm trying to do this for a Case that has no Account attached to it but as far as I see I try to not have these Cases updated by not adding them to the accountIds Set in the first place.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It also seems to occur while mass changing ownership via the listview

Answer (score 1):

I would change the following For loop from:

```
   for(Case c: Trigger.new) {  
        c.MerchantOwner__c = userMap.get(accountMap.get(c.AccountId).OwnerId).name;
    }
```

To

```
    for(Case c: Trigger.new) {  
        if (c.AccountId != null                                        // Make sure there is an Account linked to the Case
          && accountMap.ContainsKey(c.AccountId)                       // Make sure our Account query captured  it
          && accountMap.get(c.AccountId).OwnerId != null               // Make sure that account has an owner
          && usermap.ContainsKey(accountMap.get(c.AccountId).Ownerid)  // Finally make sure our User query found the owner
        ){
            c.MerchantOwner__c = userMap.get(accountMap.get(c.AccountId).OwnerId).name;
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do I format code in an answer...

Anyway I changed my code last night into:

`for(Case c: Trigger.new) {
    if(accountMap.containsKey(c.AccountId)) {
        Account a = accountMap.get(c.AccountId);
        if(userMap.containsKey(a.OwnerId)) {
            c.MerchantOwner__c = userMap.get(a.OwnerId).name;
        }
    }
}`

This seems to be the same way as your suggested or do you see any differences?

Comment: Programming Style and Readability aside, they functionally should be the same.  You aren't checking the case to make sure that it is linked to an Account (making AccountId null), but accountMap should never have a null key, so no impact there.  Out of curiosity, why did you create an instance Account a and not a instance User u?